# Erlang SNMP functions

Tags: erlang, snmp

I'm not found Erlang module with functions snmpget and snmpwalk:

module:snmpget(Host, Port, Community, Oid) -> Value

module:snmpwalk(Host, Port, Community, Oid) -> [Values]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple implementation of 'snmp walk': https://github.com/ates/snmpcl

Links:

- Manual: http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/snmp/snmp.pdf
- SNMP Quick Start: https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php/SNMP_Quick_Start